# devise new_user_session_path & new_user_registration_path not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

for some weird reason, my sign-up and log-in links are not working.

I got it working for the first time but afterwards, the link redirects me to the root path of my app.

here's the routes file.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'pages/about'

  devise_for :users

  resources :posts

  root to: "pages#home"

end
```

and here's what the rails server logs whenever i click the links

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-15 09:51:47 +0800
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-15 09:51:47 +0800
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered layouts/_landing.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 90ms (Views: 89.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

and for my views i used the following links.

```
<li><%= link_to "Log-in", new_user_session_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Sign-up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
```

can someone please tell what am I missing here? thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

This happens when you already have a user session active. Probably you are trying to access sign_in or sign_out routes when you are already signed in. Devise will by default redirect you in this case.